# How to specify different --strip (-p) levels for patch?

Tags: diff, patch

If I have a diff that has paths like these:

```
--- a/b/foo/bar/baz.pl
+++ c/foo/bar/baz.pl
```

Is there a way to tell the patch utility that the diff roots are at different levels?  i.e. -p2 for one, yet -p1 for the other.  Or is there any alternative utility that will patch in such a case?

Comment: I understand that I can move the directories around, or use symlinks, but I'm wondering if the patch util can just be smart enough to take another switch or argument to handle it.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried it with just the right -p for one or the other?  I think patch will try both and apply to whichever file actually exists.

Comment: @Walter: Thanks.  That's a good idea to try, and it makes sense.